# Amazon ELB + Django HTTPS issues

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, amazon-elb

I have been searching on SO but none of the solutions seem to work for my case:
I have a Classic Elastic Load Balancer from AWS, passing requests to my Nginx docker containers that also proxy passes to my python Gunicorn containers.

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    ...

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
 }
```

In my Django Settings I have :

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
```

The problem is, when a request is made to an endpoint, if I `print(request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'))` I get `http` instead of `https`. This causes my DRF auto-generated doc links to be generated in `http` instead of `https`.

Is there something wrong with my configurations? 
How can I force https behind an ELB?

Comment: Why don't you just add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;` in your nginx config? Your nginx will always be serving the clients using https...right?

Comment: i edited my question with the rest of my configuration for that part. so basically i already had it.

Comment: @TarunLalwani looks like your advice ended up fixing my issue. i did proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; and it now works. for some reason $scheme did not seem to set it as https any idea why? nevertheless if you make an official answer ill mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

in your nginx config. Your nginx will always be serving the clients using https as the ELB is configured to receive `https` traffic.

Also the reason `$scheme` may not have worked is because your nginx is still on `http` protocol and not `https` protocol

Answer (score 0):

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
```

Comment: Are you able to add an explanation of why this solves the problem?